# Cannot run ready project

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-storm

I'm new in Java,
I imported a ready project and when run it I got this

```
Resource Path Location Type The project was not built since its build
path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for
storm.trident.state.State. Fix the build path then try building this
project first-stories-twitter-master Unknown Java Problem The type

storm.trident.state.State cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
referenced from required .class files RecentTweetsDB.java
/first-stories-twitter-master/src/main/java/trident/state
```

can i find help on this ?
[image: error]

Comment: Is that ant/maven based project ? Did you try building the project using required goals ? And what do you mean by `ready project` ?

Comment: i meant that i didn't write the code, i got it from github and it's supposed to be run successfully. yes the project based maven. do you know what's error mean ?

Comment: If it is maven, did you build the `package` -- `jar`/`war` required using `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: yes i built it successfully but when i run code in eclipse i got this error !

Comment: Its completely eclipse based setting. try locating the `build path` in eclipse. Point the latest version to JAVA_HOME

Comment: Eclipse is going to need a reference to storm as well.

Comment: i'm new too in ubuntu . how can i set my JAVA_HOME i think from .bashrc but i don't know commands

Comment: how did you build this after downloading? how did you import the project? did you see a `build success` page when you build your project ?? telling what exactly have you done might help solving the issue faster

Comment: 1- from project menu build project 2- i imported many times delete it then import and have same error i posed it in another post then the last time i make new project then copy all the content of the folder and paste it in the project with the same name of it and then add missed library this way i know that's not the right way for importing but to escape from this error "The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches" 3- and i used  terminal in ubuntu to mvn clean install and it built successfully i guessed from your questions that the error from the way i imported it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add the jar to the build path of the project, to do this right click on the main project, click Build Path > Configure Build Path, you will then be presented with the Build path dialog, from here click on the Libraries tab and 'Add JARs' or 'Add external JARs' if the .jar file is outside of your project.

I am guessing you need to reference the Storm.jar file as it looks like the compiler can not find storm.trident.state.State class.  The app will not run until you resolve the build path issues!

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for replying .i added storm.jar but another errors appeared it became 74 error after added